# Select XML Data type (xml) from sql server and then save to a XML file on local machine in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, xml

I have a XML data type column in Database Table.

this way, I used to insert my XML file in to DB

```
    XmlReader XMLFile;

   XMLFile = XmlReader.Create(@"E:\coverindex1.xml", new XmlReaderSettings());
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@code_array", XMLFile));
```

Now I need to retrieve that column and save the data as XML File in local drive.

```
  String sql1 = "SELECT Code_Array FROM SecretCodeTable_1 WHERE Secret_Key = @secretKey";

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql1, con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secretKey", int.Parse(textBox1.Text));

             using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 XmlReader reader1 = cmd.ExecuteXmlReader();
                 if (reader1.Read())
                 {
                     xdoc.LoadXml(reader1["Code_Array"]);
                     xdoc.Save(@"E:\myfile.xml");

                     }
```

But I couldn't get output. Please any one correct me.!

Thank you!

Comment: If you run the query directly on SSMS, do you get the expected result?

Comment: And what happens of you use a SqlDataReader iso XmlReader ?

Comment: @Dieter ya I got out put on SSMS! but I need to retrieve from C#.

Comment: then please try the second option